# How to list only A specific group in AAD using ms graph api?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I'm using this query:

mail ge '' and securityEnabled eq true

but i want to pull only the mail address from users that in a specific group

Answer (score 0):

So you want to get all users email of a specific group. It is straight forward in MS Graph.

In MS Graph,

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/0023c709-3556-4296-a6ab-6df2a0a1113c/members?$select=id,mail
```

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: I'm using sync client to import the information from azure AD
you can look the client interface in the next pic:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15_F7Zt_CLdBeOnRICb0YmW3zgfU05_uK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @OudiCohenKashi, Please use Ms Graph to get the data.

Comment: i can't use Ms Graph.
This is a dedicated app to synchronize mailboxes with the Forcepoint system in the cloud

Comment: Please ask a new question in particular forum supporting the app.